# Show Content After Facebook Like

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-like

So is there any working code in HTML/PHP that makes certain content () available only after the user clicks the "Like" button. 
It's not an app, just an external website.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What happens if the visitor doesn't have an facebook account?

Comment: That's how make people hate your website. Please, don't. Allow comment only by FB users, but don't compel people to like something, it's a masked form of spam and its very annoying. My 2c.

Comment: Feel free to mark a correct answer :)  Hopefully this has helped quite a few people.

Answer (score 7):

There is a callback when a Facebook button is 'liked' using Javascript

It's documented here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

The event is called `edge.create` by the looks of it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to achieve your desired result - unless the user in question is also authenticated via facebook on your site, but I don't think that's the case.

The js like callback will (being a callback) only work after the user clicks like.

The thing you'd like to do is only possible within facebook pages' iframes, that are called with a signed request containing the current user's facebook id.

Comment: The op requested that the action take place after a button click (clicking the like button)